# Use glob.glob to search recursively for *.txt files, from current directory down

Tags: python

I am trying to modify below piece of code to search recursively for `*.txt` files from current  directory (directory in which I run my script) down.

```
for file in glob.glob('./*.txt'):
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be better off using os.walk rather than glob. It is designed for walking through directories like this. Try this code to get started:

```
import os
myfiles =[]
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("./"):
    for filename in filenames:
        if(filename.endswith(".txt")):
            myfiles.append("%s/%s" % (root, filename))
print myfiles
```

Comment: The comparison can be done using the [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module which is the module used by `glob` under the hood...

Comment: for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'): --- is that correct ?

Comment: In python 3.3 change to print(myfiles)